# How do I install dependencies for a single package when using npm workspaces?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-workspaces

Using [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) I have a folder structure like this

```
+-- package.json
+-- package-lock.json
+-- client
|   `-- package.json
+-- shared
|   `-- package.json
`-- server
    `-- package.json
```

Normally when creating a production build for a nodejs app I would run `npm ci --only=production` and then copy `node_modules` into a build artifact. I'm not sure how to do something like that when working with workspaces.

If I run `npm ci --only=production --workspace server` it splits the dependencies across `./node_modules` and `./server/node_modules`. Maybe I should copy (merge?) both `node_modules` into a build artifact?

Another option could be to copy `./package-lock.json` and `./server/package.json` into a fresh directory and run `npm ci --only=production`. It does seem to work but I don't know enough about npm to know if this is a good idea.

The requirements are:

1. `node_modules` should only include production dependencies for the chosen package
2. The dependency versions should be determined by `package-lock.json`.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @ReedHermes I kind of got it working with `npm ci --only=production --workspace server` but it does mean the artifact has an extra directory level which is a bit annoying. I was having a few issues with npm workspaces like this https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3847 so ending up dropping them for now.

Comment: on the flip side, is there a way to only install root depencies in the root level package.json?

Answer (score 0):

The split between `node_modules` and `server/node_modules` is due to hoisting. If there were a way to disable hoisting, then all dependencies of `server` would be installed to `server/node_modules`. However, current versions of npm do not provide a way to disable hoisting for workspaces.

There is discussion about adding such a feature in the following issues:

- [[RRFC] Add nohoist option for workspaces #287](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/issues/287)
- [Define which dependencies are shared among workspace projects #375](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/375)

Comment: There is already a nested install strategy so an option to not hoist seems redundant. However, the nested install strategy appears to be broken for workspaces: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6537

Answer (score -1):

I would use a combination of [`install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install) configuration options.

Using Node v18.16.0 and npm v9.7.2 here is the output of `npm install --help` (npm >= v9.7.2 is required to [correctly omit dev dependencies](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6441)):

```
$ npm install --help
Install a package

Usage:
npm install [<package-spec> ...]

Options:
[-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
[-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global]
[--install-strategy <hoisted|nested|shallow|linked>] [--legacy-bundling]
[--global-style] [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
[--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
[--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
[-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
[-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]

aliases: add, i, in, ins, inst, insta, instal, isnt, isnta, isntal, isntall

Run "npm help install" for more info
```

In this case, I would suggest a combination of

- [`install-strategy`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install#install-strategy) (`nested`)
- [`omit`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install#omit) (`dev`)
- [`workspace`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install#workspace) (`server`)

So from the workspaces root:

```
npm install --install-strategy=nested --omit=dev --workspace=server
```

You may or may not need `-install-strategy`.

This should leave a `node_modules` directory at the root of the workspaces with only the dependencies defined in the `server` workspace's package.json file with those defined in `devDependencies` omitted. You can also `--omit=peer` to remove `peerDependencies` from the `server` workspace as well.

**NOTE**: Depending on your dependency graph, this could still leave multiple `node_modules` directories that would require combining to create the artifact, i.e. [`--install-strategy=nested` does not appear to be working correctly for npm workspaces](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6537). However, the installed deps should correctly be isolated to the workspace passed in `--workspace`. Here is an [example repo](https://github.com/morganney/npm-workspaces) showing how those dependencies could be combined.

Comment: This doesn't work. Even with `--install-strategy=nested`, `npm install` splits the server dependencies between `node_modules` and `server/node_modules`. And even if it did work, it would have the downsides of the nested strategy (very deep directory structures, no de-duplicating).

Comment: I suppose item 1 has an implicit “root” node_modules. Looking at the title one could argue the suggested answer does provide installed production deps for only one workspace that could be used to build an artifact. Might be useful down the road.